# I have several select, how do I select only one option to true and set the others to false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I select only one option to true and set all others to false, regardless of select which user to choose the real option?

**Note:** User can not choose two options true.

```
  $(function() {
        $('select[name="verdadeira[]"]').change(function() {

            $('select[name="verdadeira[]"]').each(function() {


                if($(this).val() == 'V'){
                   $(this).val('V');
                }



            });
        });
    });

     <select class="form-control v" name="verdadeira[]" style="width: 120px; height: 37px; float: left;" >
            <option value="F" selected="selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Falsa</option>
            <option value="V">Verdadeira</option>
        </select>

        <select class="form-control v" name="verdadeira[]" style="width: 120px; height: 37px; float: left;" >
            <option value="F" selected="selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Falsa</option>
            <option value="V">Verdadeira</option>
        </select>

        <select class="form-control v" name="verdadeira[]" style="width: 120px; height: 37px; float: left;" >
             <option value="F" selected="selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Falsa</option>
             <option value="V">Verdadeira</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: And where is your jQuery/js code? did you try something?

Comment: Instead of dropdown use radio button here.

Comment: `$('.v').val('F').eq(0).val('V')`

Comment: Thank you! those who tried to help, though resolve otherwise.   function selected_opcao(x) {
        if (x.value == 'V') {
            $(x).removeClass('v');
            $('.v').val('F');
        }
         $(x).addClass('v');
    }